# Save language preference for future visit

Tags: i18n-l10n

I would like to achieve this:When a user selects a language in a multilingual site,when he visits this site into future,the site remembers its language previous selection and shows this language for the user.
Is there a module for this or I need to write something with cookies?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are two modules, [Language Cookie](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_cookie) and [Locale Cookie](https://www.drupal.org/project/locale_cookie).  Both work about the same, but both have problems if you are using Varnish as a cache.  There was some work on Language Cookie done to fix this, but I haven't been able to get it working with Varnish yet.  If you're not working with Varnish, though, it works great.